# Поставить пробел после второго вхождения слеша

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть например строка:
"Слово/Текст с пробелами/Еще какой-то текст/ и тут тоже может быть текст/ и так далее"

Нужно регулярное выражение для замены второго, именно второго "/" на "/ " (с пробелом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Слово/Текст с пробелами/Еще какой-то текст/ и тут тоже может быть текст/ и так далее".replace(/(.+?\/)(.+?\/)/i, "$1$2 ")
```

Получаем:

> "Слово/Текст с пробелами/ Еще какой-то текст/ и тут тоже может быть текст/ и так далее"